# Bounded continuous function from uncountable ordinal set

Tags: general-topology

Prove that if $f: w_1\rightarrow R$ is continuous, $f$ is also bounded.

**My attempt** I'm trying to use the fact that since $f$ is continuous, $f$ maps every open sets in $w_1$, which are of the form $[a,b)$ to every open sets in $R$, which are of the form  $(c,d)$. If $\ f$ is not bounded, then certainly there exists some points $p$ such that $f(p)=\infty$ or $-\infty$.

But I couldn't proceed further from here to reach the contradiction. Can someone please give me some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A continuous function does not necessarily map open sets to open sets: its *inverse* does, but it need not. For example, the function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto x^2$ takes the open set $(-1,1)$ to the set $[0,1)$, which is not open.

Try this instead. If $f$ is not bounded, then for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is an $\alpha_n\in\omega_1$ such that $|f(\alpha_n)|\ge n$. Let $P=\{n\in\Bbb Z^+:f(\alpha_n)>0\}$. At least one of $P$ and $\Bbb Z^+\setminus P$ must be infinite, and without loss of generality we may assume that $P$ is infinite. (Why?) Then $\langle\alpha_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ has a subsequence $\langle\alpha_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}f(\alpha_{n_k})=\infty$, and we might as well avoid the nested subscripts and assume that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\alpha_n)=\infty$.

Now show

- that $\langle\alpha_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ has an infinite strictly increasing subsequence $\langle\alpha_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ and
- that this subsequence has a limit in $\omega_1$,

and use the continuity of $f$ to derive a contradiction.

(By the way, a stronger result is true: if $f$ is continuous, it is eventually constant, meaning that there are a $\beta\in\omega_1$ and $r\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(\alpha)=r$ whenever $\beta\le\alpha<\omega_1$.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful hint, Prof. Scott. I was able to prove the first two points (for the 2nd point, is it because $w_1$ is union of closed sets, which means it's closed?). However, I haven't seen why the continuity of $f$ can imply a contradiction. Can you please help with this last point?

Comment: @Prof. Scott: I seriously got stuck on the continuity part that implies the contradiction:P

Comment: @user177196: The increasing subsequence has a supremum $\alpha$, to which it converges. Continuity of $f$ then implies that $\langle f(\alpha_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges to $f(\alpha)$, but that’s impossible, since $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}f(\alpha_{n_k})=\infty$.

Comment: @Prof. Scott: Many thanks for your patience. What I was confused at the beginning was why at the supremum $a$, $f(a)$ can't be ∞?

Comment: @user177196: No, because $f$ is a function from $\omega_1$ to $\Bbb R$, and $\infty\notin\Bbb R$; $f(\alpha)$ has to be a real number.

Comment: Many thanks, Prof. Scott!!

Comment: @user177196: You're welcome!